# Vlc Python Bindings unable to set time

Tags: python, python-3.x, vlc

I'm trying to play a video from a set time using the VLC python bindings. How I am doing it is using  `set_time`

> set_time(self, i_time, b_fast)
>
> Set the movie time (in ms). This has no effect if no media is being >played. Not all formats and protocols support this.
>
> Parameters:
>
> > b_fast - prefer fast seeking or precise seeking.
> >       i_time - the movie time (in ms).
>
> Returns:
>
> > 0 on success, -1 on error.

But every time I do that the video starts at the beginning.

I've tried calling the function by doing `set_time(i_time=xx)` with and without i_time. I tried giving it a time by giving it seconds and milliseconds but no luck.

I've also tried calling it immediately when I initialize the video file and when I played the video file but no luck.

My Code:

```py
  Instance = vlc.Instance()
  player = Instance.media_player_new()
  Media = Instance.media_new(self.video)
  player.set_media(Media)
  time = None

  ...
  ...

  time = int(matches[0].start.total_seconds() * 1000) 
  # matches[0] = Subtitle(index=1, start=datetime.timedelta(0, 33, 843000), end=datetime.timedelta(0, 38, 97000), content='this is a sentence', proprietary='')
  # matches[0].start.total_seconds() = 33.843

  player.play()
  print(player.set_time(time))
```

I expect the video to start from the set time but everytime i print `player.set_time()` it returns `None`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a `start_time` option to the media or wait very briefly for play to start and then use the set_time option.
Here is the `Media.add_option` version.

```
import vlc
import time
url = "file:///home/rolf/GWPE.mp4"

playing = set([1,2,3,4])
instance=vlc.Instance()
player=instance.media_player_new()
media = instance.media_new(url)
media.add_option('start-time=600.00') # 600 seconds (10 minutes)
player.set_media(media)
player.play()
time.sleep(0.1) # wait briefly for it to start
while True:
    state = player.get_state()
    if state not in playing:
        break
```